# Why ASP.NET-Core web & api is consuming more memory over server and how can I reduce it?

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm using ASP.NET-Core MVC for web and api. API is being used in ASP.NET-Core MVC project also but after upload to server it's using too much memory and may create problem in future to hang or slow down the server so can you please suggest how can I reduce the memory usage of my project?

One more thing that in this project we are using many ajax callings and also some functions are calling in background on each 1 min so will it cause the issue?

Please guide me to reduce the memory usage of my project on server.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Without seeing your code, it's difficult for us to say where the problem lies. Please [edit] your post to contain a [mcve].

Comment: Sounds like a premature optimization for me. Do you have any specific performance problems? Doesn't look like.

Comment: You can do some load testing first to see how the app reacts to an expected load. Only after having some real numbers, you can say is there a memory problem or not.

Comment: You can profile your code to find what is consuming memory the most. Usually, memory problems are because of the memory leaks. Review how you use statics and singletons.